# Comparing three indices in a multidimensional array in java resulting in an out-of-bounds exception

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm currently making a tic-tac-toe game using multidimensional arrays in java, and I seem to have hit a wall here. I'm comparing three indices to find out if they're the same (to declare a winner). I've found that I can successfully compare two with no exceptions thrown. However, if I compare three, an out of bounds exception is thrown after displaying that the user has won (horizontally). I'm really unsure of what's going on. The array is 5-by-5 and is of type String, with all values initially set to " ". I'm pretty illiterate with this website, so I'm sorry if the question was formatted improperly!! Please let me know so that I can improve! :)
Code:

```
for (int row = 0; row < testArray.length; row++)
        {
            for (int column = 0; column < testArray[row].length; column++)
            {
                if ((testArray[row][column].equals("x")) && (testArray[row][column + 2].equals("x")) && (testArray[row][column + 4].equals("x")))
                    System.out.println("You win!");

                if (!(column % 2 == 0))
                    testArray[row][column] = "|";

                else if (!(row % 2 == 0))
                    testArray[row][column] = "-";

                System.out.print(testArray[row][column]);
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
```

Thank you so so much in advance!

Edit: For reference, I'm typing row = 0, column = 0. r=0 col=0 is then set to x.
An iteration happens, r=0, col=2 is set to x, and then it asks again. When I get to r=0, col=4 is when the exception happens.

Comment: testArray[row][column + 2] and testArray[row][column + 4] will be a problem with indices close to testArray[row].length

Comment: @mettleap I changed it to [row][0].equals("x") , [row][2] etc and it works, but i'm a little unsatisfied. I've got a couple questions for you, if that's alright! 1. What exactly was going wrong with my former code? 2. Is there a better way to do it? Don't feed me the answer, but maybe give me a little hint if there's a better option available? Thank you for responding btw!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line you cannot use:

```
((testArray[row][column].equals("x"))  
   &&(testArray[row][column + 2].equals("x")) 
   && (testArray[row][column + 4].equals("x"))
```

For columns greater than 3 it will throw an `IndexOutOfBoundException`. So you should have that `2` and `4` as variables and adjust according to the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

The error you have is in this line:

```
if ((testArray[row][column].equals("x")) && (testArray[row][column + 2].equals("x")) && (testArray[row][column + 4].equals("x")))
```

The reason this line causes out-of-bounds exception is because the array that corresponds to `testArray[row][column + 2]` may not exist.

Consider the case where the for loop that iterates over column reaches

`column = testArray[row][length-1]`

This means that column + 2 = (length - 1) + 2 = length + 1.

The exact same error occurs for 
`testArray[row][column + 4]`

Hopefully this clears things up.